# nyc equivalent of istanbul command

Tags: istanbul, nyc

I am trying to convert my `istanbul` code coverage commands to `nyc`.

It appears as though `nyc` is now the command line interface for the istanbul test coverage library.

With istanbul, we'd get coverage like so:

```
istanbul cover foo.js --dir coverage
```

then we'd get a consolidated report like so:

```
istanbul report --dir coverage --include **/*coverage.json lcov
```

so I am trying to determine what the equivalent command is with `nyc` -

to get coverage with nyc, it looks like I can do this:

```
nyc node foo.js  # writes coverage data to .nyc_output
```

but when I look in .nyc_output, there are a bunch of .json files but they don't seem to have any data in them.

If I try to get a report, using

```
nyc report --reporter=lcov
```

That report command doesn't seem to do anything, the `.nyc_output` directory looks the same as before:

[image]

Note I am fine with using configuration files and avoiding extra commands at the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Official documentation](https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc) proposes using it like this:

```
nyc --reporter=lcov npm test
```

Comment: so the coverage and report command are one and the same? But I need to get a consolidated report for multiple processes, not just one process.

Comment: why not make consolidated coverage in one step?

Comment: because I need to consolidate the coverage for multiple processes not just one process - my use case is a little different - it's for a library not an application